# Do Heroku pipeline stages correspond to Rails environment stages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pipeline

I just created my first Heroku pipeline and deployed a Rails app to its `development` stage.

My question is, do these pipeline stages (like `development` and `production`) correspond to the environments in Rails? For example, does my app deployed to the `development` stage get its settings from `config/development.rb`? Or do all apps deployed in Heroku read from `production.rb` regardless of pipeline stage?

I know it seems like a basic question but I couldn't find info in the docs or here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's always the rails' production environment. Anyway, you could just try it (check the log when the server starts, it should say the current environment)

Comment: Thank you and good point. I somehow didn't think of simply checking the log. Seems like it's `production` regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to settings -> reveal config vars, there should be an env variable called RAILS_ENV, which you can set to the environment you want. By default it is production.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone viewing this and for future reference - as @arieljuod guessed, it's `production`.

Console output:

```
Running rails c on ⬢ intg-app... up, run.3149 (Free)
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.3)
```